# Bootloop & Cannot get into any recovery mode stock/CMW/TWRP

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

My Samsung s4 mini (I9190) is in bootloop.

I CANNOT go into recovery mode by power+home+volume up.

I CAN go into download mode by power+volume down.

"Firmware upgrade and initialisation" by Kies finished succesfully but it is still in bootloop.

"Odin + Sammobile firmware" finished succesfully but it is still in bootloop.

"Odin + CMW Recovery" finished succesfully but it is still in bootloop.
(http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2528136&d=1390237165 )

"Odin + TWRP Recovery" finished succesfully but it is still in bootloop.
(http://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=file-thanks&fid=24052804347763027&mid=108&download_id=ovsrhlssjl8oa3tm4aanrrh1u0&tid=1453125230&hc=25a981cade4149663a73da4c332838c193eb9489524be94632c813efd7fed5f7 )

Any suggestions?

Details:

It was Android 4.2.2; the original OS in it when I bought it. Then one day I rooted it. I did not upgrade the OS. It was still the original TouchWiz on 4.2.2. (No CyanogenMod or anything....) Everything was fine for 1 year. Then one morning I clicked on a whatsapp message and my phone restarted & has gone into a bootloop.

I do not have an external SD card. I tried two different batteries, each works fine in another phone. I did not insert an SD card or SIM card during any of these processes.

Comment: Have you already reflashed the stock ROM with Odin? And make sure you are holding the correct buttons. (Hold Volume Up, Power Button and Home Button at the same time).

Comment: I do not know what a stock rom is. is there a link that i can download or a document that explains how to do it?

Comment: Here you can download the correct ROM: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9190/ (Registration needed). Then you can flash the firmware (ROM) with Odin. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: I did it. "Odin + Sammobile firmware" finished succesfully but it is still in bootloop.

Comment: @lembas Did you finish it already? How did you download the file + flash the firmware so fast?

Comment: @beeshyams It was Android 4.2.2; the original OS in it when I bought it. Then one day I rooted it. I did not upgrade the OS. It was still the original TouchWiz on 4.2.2. (No CyanogenMod or anything....) Everything was fine for 1 year. Then one morning I clicked on a whatsapp message and my phone restarted & has gone into a bootloop.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I did it before asking this question. I wrote it on the original question that "Odin + Sammobile firmware" finished succesfully but it is still in bootloop.

Comment: @beeshyams I do not have an external SD card. I tried two different batteries, each works fine in another phone. I did not insert an SD card or SIM card during any of these processes.

Comment: @beeshyams yes :...(

Comment: Although I dont't think the service center will do it for free, because you have void your warranty.

Comment: Thank you very much to you both. Warranty has already ended before I rooted the phone.

Comment: accidentally hit on chat link. sorry. - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34488/discussion-between-lembas-and-superthomaslab).

Comment: please provide some more details and try another firmware for your device. here http://live.samsung-updates.com/index.php?device=GT-I9190 you can see that each region has its own specific rom for a device.the stock rom that was specific to your region will only work in your device. more details http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-mini .  Was your phone locked to a network? If so reinstall the network firmware as the partition size will be correct.

Comment: It isn't locked to a network. I tried Turkish region. (http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2528136&d=1390237165) It didn't work.